# Going to any line in a file without changing the code manually

Tags: shell-script

I have a file named full_path.txt where it has a few hundred lines of directory paths.Right now I'm able to go to any path by modifying the shell script i wrote and grep what i need.
i find it tedious to go to the code, change it, save it and then run it again to get to the desired line and grep what i want.

I want to know if there is a way to add something to the end of the script so that it automatically takes me to that line and greps.

I know the thing I have to do is change the FNR to whichever line i want, but is there a way to do it while I run it?
for example if i want to go to line 15, i can just  type `gotoline.sh 15`

This is the code i have so far

```
line=$(awk 'FNR==1' full_path.txt) 
cd "${line}" 
grep -a "RESULT:" console_debug.log > Result.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** gives the ability to pass input arguments/variables to a script (via `-v` option):

```
#!/bin/bash

line=$(awk -v l_num=$1 'NR == l_num' full_path.txt)
...
```

With the approach above you can pass the needed argument when running main shell script:

```
gotoline.sh 15
```

where `15` will be passed as shell script argument `$1`

Comment: @VineethThomas, you're welcome

Comment: You could also do `line=$(sed -n "${1}p" full_path.txt)` if you like brevity.